# Constant grinding from rear wheel?

Tags: chevrolet, noise, impala, grinding

Recently a rear track bar broke on my 2010 Chevy Impala, 160K miles, resulting in that tire swinging all over the place going down the road. I've replace the track bar, but now there is a constant metalic grinding noise coming from that wheel. This is whether it is turned by hand up on a jack or while driving. There's no play when I try and twist the wheel, and the noise is consistent when driving and turning (other than gradually getting louder with increased speed.) I've checked the rotor backing plate and I don't believe it's making contact.

Is it likely that the bearings need to be replace, or could there be another problem?

Comment: Yes, sounds like bearings - loading them like that driving with the wheel so badly positioned was the cause...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the sound was actually the rotor backing plate. But it was not on the outside of the place where it can be bent out pretty easily. I had to take the rotor off to access the inside where it was rubbing.

Once I had bent that out, nearly all of the grinding went away, but there was still another sound, though a bit quieter. Turned out the bearings also were bad.

Comment: them dust covers always a hidden problem